# How to change developer environment saved connections?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav

My developer environment is always trying to connect to an old instance which is no longer working:

[image]

I've checked in AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\140\ClientUserSettings.config but I see that's only for the client...

How can I change this details to connect to another server?

Answer (score 1):

You mixing up the concepts. In most cases if you say `Instance` you mean nav server's instance. But on the screenshot you have dev environment which connects to database on sql rather than to server instance. There is actually a place where nav instance is specified in dev env (it is used to open RTC when you trying to run object). So be more precise. I assume you mean what is on screenshot then.

Dev Env stores last used parameters. So if you open one copy of dev env, select server and database, connect to is **successfully** and then close the dev env, it will save connection parameters you just used. And will use them nex time you run it.

If that is not what is happening then check those:

1. Link you are using to open dev env. [Connection parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/using-the-development-environment-from-the-command-prompt) might be included into it.
2. Check if you have rights to modify file where dev env stores it's parameters ([zup.file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/saving-setup-parameters-in-the-zup-file)).

When you have multiple copies of dev env opened and you start closing them, dev env will ask you if you want to overwrite zup file. That is it. It asks you if you want to save your setting (including connection, windows possition inside dev env and so on).